# How to permanently raise/lower Bravery/Faith stats in Final Fantasy Tactics: War of the Lions?

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics

I've recently started playing FFT: WotL on iOS, and learned from the wiki sites that the Bravery and Faith stats determine various important factors in combat (frequency of reaction commands, effectiveness of spells, etc) and how Ramza's "Steel" ability can raise someone else's Bravery, but the effect of that ability doesn't seem to last after combat.

However, I have been keeping track of some of my characters' Bravery/Faith stats and they *do* change from time to time, but so far I haven't really found rhyme or reason to it.

Are there any guides that explain whether it's possible to permanently raise the Bravery stat, and if so, how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *permanent* boost from effects like Ramza's skills and the lectures of a Orator is only a *fraction* of the change you see during battle. Ramza may be able to raise a unit's Bravery by 5, but the permanent boost is only going to be 1. The same goes for the Orator's skills that raise or lower Bravery and Faith (and, to point, the Orator is the only way to boost Faith in this fashion).

As such, if you want significant boosts to your Bravery or Faith stats in either direction, you need to be using the abilities to alter your Bravery and Faith stats repeatedly during battle. In due time, you'll see the impact. Keep in mind, however, that with the permanent stats: a unit who hits 5 Bravery or lower will leave your army out of fright, while a unit who hits 98 Faith or higher will leave your army out of religious enlightenment (this latter one means the actual Faith stat, so being under the "Faith" status effect doesn't cause this). So be wary while you play around with these and make sure not to go so far as to lose your units!

Comment: This FAQ says that the permanent change of bravery or faith is 1/4 of the in-fight change, rounded down. This goes for either positive or negative change. Search for "00brave" here: http://www.gamefaqs.com/iphone/638808-final-fantasy-tactics-the-war-of-the-lions/faqs/50422

Comment: The amount of bravery/faith that is added or subtracting during combat and the remaining applied to the character permanently should be included in the answer.